# Generate a 2D/3D/n-dimensional uncertain data set with/without label

Tags: benchmarking, data-visualization, uncertainty

I am going to work on uncertainty visualization. My main problem is finding/generating a 2D/3D/n-dimensional data set with uncertain data.

How do I can generate/create a data set which includes uncertain data (with and/or without label)? Is there any benchmarking data set?

Comment: Do you have a particular programming framework you wish to produce this in? What exactly do you mean by "uncertain" data? (real data with uncertainties, perhaps?)

Comment: I need a data set which naturally includes uncertain data. This uncertain data can come from error, imprecision, noise through e.g., sensors.

Answer (score 0):

After my hardly working and searching, I could find some results:

Actually, there is no a benchmarking data set with uncertainties features. One solution is adding noise to the original data set to make uncertainties due to affection of the noise.
The ideal way is application of `White Gaussian Noise`. Two ways are as follows:

(1) MATLAB can support this issue with the function [`wgn`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/wgn.html).

(2) using `randn` function from MATLAB.

(3) my suggestion is using `Mean * randn(n,1) + Standard Deviation`, which add noise in your data set with your preferred `mean` and `Std. (Standard Deviation)`

I hope that my recommendation being useful.